# Modified Memory too High? 16gb of Memory and a few programs open = "Not enough Memory" errors

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, memory, resource-monitor

I keep having to restart my computer after leaving it on for a day or so in Windows because my "Modified memory" (whatever that is) goes absurdly high and I begin getting "Memory too low" errors, despite having 16GiB of memory.

[image: http://s11.postimg.org/hulr1egvn/memorytoolow.png]

I have no idea what to do here. How do you force free modified memory? I have 10GB free on my primary SSD if that matters and a 32gb pagefile.

Hardware:

> **Operating System** Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1
>
> **CPU** Intel Core i7 2600K @ 3.40GHz
>
> **RAM** 16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 802MHz (9-9-9-24)
>
> **Motherboard** ASUSTeK Computer INC. P8Z68-V GEN3 (LGA1155)
>
> **Monitors** DELL U2410 (1920x1200@59Hz) & Acer AL1916 (1280x1024@60Hz)
>
> **Video Cards** 2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti (EVGA) & 2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti (EVGA)
>
> **Storage** 1863GB ATA WDC WD2002FAEX-0 SCSI Disk Device (SATA) & 238GB ATA Samsung SSD 840 SCSI Disk Device (SSD)
>
> **Optical Drives** ATAPI iHBS112 2 SCSI CdRom Device (Blu-ray read/write)
>
> **Audio** Creative X-Fi Audio Processor (WDM)
>
> **Peripherals** Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920, Logitech Performance MX Mouse,
>   Genius SW-G2.1 2000 - 45 Watts RMS Speakers, Dell 101-Key Keyboard

Comment: Why are you trying to force the memory to be free, if its required, Windows will allocate it to your task.  **"Memory too low" errors is a virtual memory problem**

Comment: Do you use a Broadcom WIFI device? If yes, update the driver or stop the program BCMWLTRY.EXE

Comment: Look at my screenshot though - the Modified Memory is *huge*. And I only have Chrome open with two tabs, Skype, Pidgin, a word document open, and Steam. That's it. I shouldn't be getting "out of memory" errors on 16gb of RAM with this setup!

No Broadcom Wifi sadly.

Comment: post your used hardware please.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Post has been updated with my hardware!

Comment: If you want to get rid of `Modified memory` (that is done by flushing the data to disk), you can try RAMMAp. http://i.imgur.com/HEY2p6s.png

Comment: You have the large modified memory because the Commit charge is 100% and it cannot be written to the page file. As the commit of processes doesn't add up to 48GB, it is likely to be a driver leaking Paged Pool. You can use Poolmon to check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/08/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-2-poolmon.aspx

Comment: what are your network adapters. Also do this http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa and give me the trace, maybe I see more details.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a memory leak.  Can you run [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) and post a screen shot of the Memory tab from the System overview screen? (double-click the graphs at the top to open this).

Comment: @Twisty After a thorough scanning of my hard drives with several antivirus programs, the problem hasn't reproduced itself since. If it happens again though (sometimes it takes a day or two of being on), I'll post that screenshot.

Comment: Ok. It's usual for a memory leak to take some time to reoccur anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In my case purely through trial and error, I tracked it down to runSW.exe (some Realtek application with corresponding service. Not clear what use it actually has)

As soon as I stopped this service, my System Commit, Physical Memory usage, and that dreaded 'Modified Memory' all dropped off like a cliff.

Comment: Realtek is very popular among m/board manufacturers for sound and Ethernet chipsets.  Check for updated drivers for these; they might fix that bug for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "out of memory" errors because your commit charge is at 100%, and some program is trying to allocate more private commit.

Do you have a pagefile? If not, create one. If you do, make it bigger, or add another.

Or, check task manager for the program(s) with the most "commit size", and close some of them.

The system cannot write most modified pages without a pagefile.

Comment: I have a 32gb pagefile. That should be more than enough I would think. And if you check out my screenshot, the committed memory isn't terribly high.

Comment: The graph in the right column shows that your committed memory is at 100%.

Comment: That is correct, but if you look at the list of processes, it is arranged by committed memory and if you add the numbers up, they don't add up to anywhere near 16gb. They add up to about 2.4gb, which matches my "In use" memory. The remainder of the memory seems to be eaten up by this mysterious "modified memory" section.

Comment: @user798080 Probably you have hundreds of processes that each by one make a total use of 100%.

Comment: @LittleHelper I've added them up and they don't come anywhere close. As I said above, they end up adding up to about 2.4gb. Not 16 (and that's ignoring my 32gb pagefile).

Comment: @user798080 You counted only the first ones. Also the system takes that memory too and you can't tell how much it takes.

Comment: @LittleHelper I've added them *all* up too. It took awhile. Trust me, that's not true.

Comment: The "commit charge" graph doesn't lie. Furthermore it is consistent with your "out of memory" error, so we have independent confirmation. What does your paged pool look like? That contributes to commit charge too, and it's not in any process. Let's see Task Manager's Performance tab.

Comment: btw, the "in use" number there is physical memory, "commit charge" is virtual. You're comparing apples to oranges. It's only coincidence that the two numbers are similar on your machine. There's a lot of physical memory that's "in use" but is not used by committed virtual memory.

Comment: Also btw, you can add up all processes' values of a counter like commit charge a lot more easily with Performance Monitor.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Sadly I had to restart my computer in order to use it. There were several system updates, so I figured installing them might help (they required a reboot). Next time this happens, I'll take a look at that. Until then, I'm doing several virus scans.

Comment: If you see it again, remember these points: 1. The "system is running low on memory" or "...is out of memory" popup happens when the commit charge + a request for more private commit exceeds the commit limit; it has nothing to do with RAM. 2. The TM graph shows that your commit charge is very close to the commit limit already, given little room for any new allocations. 3. The commit limit is equal to the size of RAM + the current size of your pagefile. SO: To get rid of that error, either run less stuff at one time that contributes to commit charge, or add RAM, or increase your pagefile size.

Comment: Ran out of room. Sentence 1 should end with "it has nothing to do with FREE RAM." Sorry.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan I'll say what I said before though... I was only running about 3-4 different programs (Chrome, Skype, Steam, and OpenOffice) simultaneously and I have a 32gb pagefile. I don't suspect it has anything to do with any natural cause of me hitting my limit.

Comment: There are many things that contribute to commit charge besides process's "Commit" as shown in that display.

Answer (score 0):

Has it always done this?
Have you run a mem test?
What does the commit look like when you restart; do the numbers still not add up?
Over/under clocking?

I'd rather have put these question in a comment.

Comment: This hasn't always happened. It started a couple weeks ago with a windows update. I don't know which. Memtest passes just fine.

Comment: I had an update 2-3 weeks ago that failed and ran a restore point to get around it.  This week's patch Tuesday went off without a hitch. Personally, I would go with a restore point first.  If that didn't work, I'd look at an intermittent mem fault.  I'd pull half of my memory and see if that fixed it. If it didn't, I'd replace it with the other half.  Also, I'd cut my pagefile down to 2 gig and NOT let Windows manage it. From your usage prints, you only need a pagefile for crash-dumps.

Comment: And Your "Hard Faults" seem very high. That's a pagefile issue.

Comment: if it's a pagefile issue, what should be done? I already have a 32gb pagefile.

Comment: I think the hard faults reflect your problem and don't change what I have already suggested to do.